# Several enum classes that declare constants with the same names

Tags: java, enum

I'm working on a Java library for sorts for Magic: the Gathering.  Well, without going into a lot of detail, in the game there are five different colors of magic: `white`, `blue`, `black`, `red`, and `green`.  That's easy enough, that's a textbook example of an enum.  However, there's a problem: there are several variations on these colors.  There are your standard variants, the "monocolored hybrid" variants, and the "Phyrexian" variants (don't ask).  So, my question is, which of these is a better approach?

Idea 1:

```
enum Symbol {
  WHITE,
  BLUE,
  BLACK,
  RED,
  GREEN,

  MONOCOLORED_HYBRID_WHITE,
  MONOCOLORED_HYBRID_BLUE,
...
  PHYREXIAN_WHTIE,
  PHYREXIAN_BLUE,
...
}
```

Idea 2:

```
interface Symbol {
  method1()
  method2()
...
}
enum Primary implements Symbol {
  WHITE,
  BLUE,
...
}
enum MonocoloredHybrid implements Symbol {
  WHITE,
  BLUE,
...
}
enum Phyrexian implements Symbol { ...
```

I've been using the first way for a while, but I've been starting to think the second way might be better.  It shows more clearly that these classes of symbols are different, yet still compatible, since they implement the same interface.  It will cause a little bit of boilerplate code (just a couple fields), but my main issue is I have three enum constants called `WHITE`.  Now, I'd always be referencing them by their class name, e.g., `Primary.WHITE`, but this still seems a little awkward. But perhaps it's better than the "Smurf naming" I'd have to do in the first technique.  (I also can't use them in EnumMap/ EnumSet in the second way, but I think I'm okay with that.)

So, which is the better approach?  Is it okay to have a bunch of enum classes all declaring constants with the same name?  Is there a third alternative that's even better?

Answer (score 3):

This can get confusing... and Magic The Gathering is one that loves to do exceptions to rules.  Trying to codify them can often be a challenge.

On the "MonoColored Hybrid" read [this](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1371/~/magic%3A-the-gathering%3A-monocolored-hybrid) and [this](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/748/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDA1OTgyNDkwL3NpZC9FNEM3b1RabA%3D%3D). And then [this](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2181/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDA1OTgyNDkwL3NpZC9FNEM3b1RabA%3D%3D) for Phyrexian mana.

However, this *can* boil down to something that is rather sensible.. and doesn't stick too much in a single enum or confuse the next person with an inheritance tree of enums.  Enums really 'want' to be simple things, so let them be so.  The simpler they are, the easier they are to use, and its a good thing to use enums.

A card has some cost.  The good old fashioned [lighting bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234704) is just "R".  This is a List of some sort.  It could even be empty as in the case of [0 cost artifacts](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=600) (unless you want to do [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)).  But its a List.

Each element of the list is a SpellCost object.

A SpellCost would then be composed of:

An [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) of costs.  The Enum that backs the map would be:

```
enum Mana {
  WHITE,
  BLUE,
  BLACK,
  RED,
  GREEN,
  COLORLESS
}
```

And then you would have the EnumMap be as a `EnumMap<Mana, Integer>`.  Something that was a "R/2" for "Red or two colorless" could then be specified in the EnumMap as: `mana.put(Mana.RED,1); mana.put(Mana.COLORLESS,2);`  This also handles cards that are described as "R/W G" (such as [Naya Hushblade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=188969) - because not all cards are monocolored hybrids).

<sup><sub>The EnumMap and EnumSet are two of forgotten collections that are really nice once you realize what they are and do.  They give you type safe entries in a map and are backed by either a simple array or a bitfield.  The type safety on it can prevent a number of bugs associated with bitfields.  And the type safety on the map is something to think about whoever you've got a `Map<String, Object>` and wonder what happens when there's a typo in the String.</sub></sup>

Phyrexian mana is then an attribute of the SpellCost.  Its a int (though you could do it as a boolean later and yell [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) in my general direction).  Currently the definition of the cost is "mana or two life" but I wouldn't count on that being the case forever and locking yourself into a boolean now... well.

So, you've got:

```
public class SpellCost {
    EnumMap<Mana, Integer> mana;
    int lifeCost;

    ...
}
```

And then write the associated methods for it.  You might want to write a container for the cost itself rather than leaving it as a bare `List` so that you can have appropriate methods against it.

The key design points for this is that it keeps the enum simple as enums aught to be.  Any of the complexity of the business logic is kept within the `SpellCost` class (and possibly the container class too).

Comment: Oh boy, a Magic player.  Don't worry, I'm actually doing something similar to this, with Guava Multisets, no less.  My ManaCost is made up of an int for colorless and a Multiset<Symbol>.  Also, yes, of course I'm taking into account dual-color hybrid symbols, I just felt like they were out of the scope of my question.  I'm not following how this model handles the Naya Hushblade example, though, how are you differentiating the primary and hybrid symbols?

Comment: Also, while I'm a big fan of EnumMap and EnumSet, in magic most cards really only have one type of symbol, so it's pretty much overkill.  I'm just using Guava's ImmutableMultiset because it has guaranteed iteration order and is relatively small.

Comment: Domain knowledge comes in useful in these problems sometimes.  A single color (rather than hybrid) cost would just have a single entry in the `man` EnumMap.  Thats it.  If its a hybrid, it has two (or more) costs.  One could argue that the 'COLORLESS' value isn't needed and could be done just as easily by setting a value to all the other fields in the EnumMap to be the colorless value instead.

Comment: The EnumMap also has a guaranteed iteration order - its the order of the Enum.  It is *very* small in terms of memory footprint because its just backed by an array of Objects that are indexed by the ordinal value of the enum that keys it.

Comment: Well actually, I have a Color enum also.  Each symbol has a set of colors that it represents.  In my original post I use color and symbol interchangeably; that's only because I figured I'd be dealing with non-Magic players.  How foolish of me...

Comment: If my Symbol enum has 26 constants, then that's 26 object references per map (whoops, not set).  If I only have about one symbol type per card, that's a lot of references compared to the, like, 4 object references that a singleton EnumMultiset uses.  And the reason I brought up iteration order is that a White, Blue, and Green card, for example, actually has its symbols in the order Green, White, Blue, and I want to have that implemented.

Comment: I'd suggest poking at the code for EnumMap to see how elegant its internals are ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/EnumMap.java#EnumMap)).  Glancing at the enum multi set, it appears to be just a thin layer on top of the MultiSet which while well done, isn't exactly light ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r06/com/google/common/collect/EnumMultiset.java) - note everything boils down to the abstract class).

Comment: I am aware of how cool EnumMaps are, believe me, but they do use an array the size of your enum, which, if your enum is large enough and your average map small enough, is overkill.  And again, the unusual iteration order I want to impose makes it unusable for that purpose.

Comment: Also, this is kind of off-topic.  I'd certainly be interested to get Magic players' opinions on the best design, given their knowledge of the subject, but this probably isn't the best place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15886/discussion-between-codebreaker-and-michaelt).